# discord.js check if var changed from external

Tags: javascript, variables, discord.js, var

so im making a bot and i want to check if something already happend with a non declared var`
i also made a website where html var changes with a wheel whith a file thats get readed,
my question: how to check if the var has changed...

```
 const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const cheerio = require("cheerio")
const db = require("quick.db");
const err_404 = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;http://errors.biz.nf/404.php" /></head><body></body></html>'
module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: "spin",
        aliases: ['spi', 'spinn', 'sp'],
        category: 'economy',
        description: 'spin wheel',
        usage: ' ',
        accessableby: "everyone"
    },
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {
        var user = message.member.user.tag;
        var user = user.replace("#", "");
        var spinlink = "http://miers.c1.biz/spin/index.html";
        var link = `http://miers.c1.biz/w/p/${user}.txt`;

fetch(link).then(res => res.text())
.then(html => {
    if(html != err_404){
        if (html = html_prev || html_prev == undefined){
            console.log(html_prev,html)
            html_prev = html;
            message.channel.send(`you already collected this spin, spin again`);
        }else{
        let bal = db.fetch(`money_${message.author.id}`)
        message.channel.send(`${html} added to bal \nnew balance:${bal}`);
    }
    }else {
        message.channel.send(`${message.member.user.tag} you never voted before \nvote here:${spinlink}`);
        console.log(link)
    }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: You can check if the var has changed by using `console.log([insert variable here])` between pieces of code.

Comment: never mind i fixed it but tnx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it, my new code:

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio")
const db = require("quick.db");
const { VolumeInterface } = require("discord.js");
const err_404 = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;http://errors.biz.nf/404.php" /></head><body></body></html>'
let html_prev;
let html2 = 0;
module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: "spin",
        aliases: ['spi', 'spinn', 'sp'],
        category: 'economy',
        description: 'spin wheel',
        usage: ' ',
        accessableby: "everyone"
    },
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {
        var user = message.member.user.tag;
        var user = user.replace("#", "");
        var spinlink = "http://miers.c1.biz/spin/";
        var link = `http://miers.c1.biz/w/p/${user}.txt`;

fetch(link).then(res => res.text())
.then(html => {
    fetch(link).then(res => res.text())
    .then(html3 => {
    if(html != err_404){
        if (html == html_prev){
            message.channel.send(`you already collected this spin, spin again\n here:${spinlink}`);
        }else{
            if(html2 = 0){
                html2 = html;
            }else{
        html = html3;
        html = html2;
        let bal = db.fetch(`money_${message.author.id}`)
        message.channel.send(`${html3} added to bal \nnew balance:${bal}`);
        html_prev = html3;
            }
    }
    }else {
        message.channel.send(`${message.member.user.tag} you never voted before \nvote here:${spinlink}`);
        console.log(link)
    }
    })
  })}
}
```